# How to determine RAM size of Model 4B without power?

Tags: pi-4

I wanted to buy an RPi4 on a flee market. Prices between the 1 GB, 2 GB, 4 GB and 8 GB differ a lot, so I wanted to make sure not to get scammed. The RAM size is not printed on the silk screen of the RPi4.

I found a list of RAM chips on the Internet:

```
1GB - 4HBMGCJ
2GB - D9WHZ
4GB - D9WHV
8GB - D9ZCL
```

However, the chip in question was labelled `D8CJN` and thus didn't even look similar to the ones on the list. It was a model from 2018.

What RAM size was that version? Is there a definite list of RAM chips available on the Internet? How to determine RAM size of Model 4B without power?

Comment: Some other codes mentioned here: https://support.thepihut.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006049318-Which-Raspberry-Pi-4-RAM-option-do-I-have-

Comment: What size do they claim? What price?

Comment: More codes https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/14pfdcp/worried_about_the_ram/

Comment: @CoderMike: starting price for negotiation was 80€. Which would be ok for a working 8 GB model but too much for a 4 GB model.

Comment: If they call it "a flee market" this is a warning. I wouldn't buy a used Pi unless it was demonstrated to work.

Comment: Only 15€ more for a new one https://rpilocator.com/